# How do I catch errors in inline code chunk in R Markdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I am batch-rendering a number of Rmd files in a loop using `rmarkdown::render` and I need to be able to get output even for those that have errors in inline code. I can't manually edit inline code to include things like `try()` so some kind of kniter hook is needed.

I tried writing an inline `knit_hook` that would catch inline code errors but that doesn't work because the expression is evaluated before it gets passed to the hook function.

Any suggestions would be very mcuh appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured this out in the end. The trick is to set both `inline` and `evaluate.inline` hooks. Below, `evaluate.inline` is an edit of the default function that adds `try()` to the evaluation. The `inline` hook then tests for output class and, if it's `"try-error"`, returns the object `as.vector` (without attributes):

```
knitr::knit_hooks$set(
  evaluate.inline = function (code, envir = knit_global()) {
    v = try(eval(xfun::parse_only(code), envir = envir))
    knitr::knit_print(v, inline = TRUE, options = knitr::opts_chunk$get())
  },
  inline = function(x) {
  if (any(class(x) == "try-error")) {
    as.vector(x)
  } else x
})
```

Hope others find this useful.

Comment: Good find! For `try`, I typically use `if(inherits(x, "try-error"))`, though it should be fine. You may also prefer `v <- tryCatch(eval(...), error = function(e) conditionMessage(e))`, it trims some of the "Error in try(...):" message.

Answer (score 0):

The same way you catch it in regular code?

```
---
title: 'Hello World'
---

This mistake is caught: `r tryCatch(stop("foo"), error = function(e) "caught!")`

This mistake is silent: `r try(stop("foo"), silent = TRUE)`
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. I think I wasn't clear enough in my question. I am not the author of the Rmd files and need to not have to modify every inline chunk in them. In other words, I need a more programmatic solution.

Comment: I understand, and I think you need to make that clear in your question. What you're asking for is a generic way of interrupting the error chain in R on a global level. This is actually a little "dangerous", as it is entirely possible that the results you get from the Rmd will be completely untrustworthy due to an error or two *somewhere* in the document. While I understand that you inherited the Rmd documents, the fact that you get errors suggest it might be better for you to assume ownership and/or ask the original authors to fix the errors themselves.

Comment: Thanks for your comment; I edited the question. I understand your point but that's not really a concern. Not that the context is relevant to the problem but this is for marking/checking Rmd files submitted by students.

Comment: I suspected as such, since that's about the only time I can imagine where encouraging that behavior in R is not inappropriate.

Comment: I don't have any experience with it yet, but R-4.0 introduces `globalCallingHandlers`, a function which is intended to give you some more control on how to work with errors. I am not using 4 yet so haven't played with the function, but perhaps that is a direction you can further research.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll look into it. It's just strange that there doesn't seem to be a well-documented knitr hook option for this :/