# How to pass errors back to the Rmarkdown::render function?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to render an Rmarkdown file through an R script. (Code for both files below). What I would like to do is to pass information back to the render function depending on where the error is. This may be that the file can't read the input dataset. I would like to do this as I would like to run the script as a cron job and would like it to send me an email telling me why I might need to re run the code or what the error is.

I have read some of the other stackoverflow similar questions and couldn't see how it did what I wanted with some testing.

The r script: (I have attempted using something like the following)

```r
rm(list = ls())
setwd("C:/Users/joel.kandiah/Downloads")


a <- print(try(rmarkdown::render("test.Rmd", quiet = T), TRUE))
#> [1] "C:/Users/joel.kandiah/Downloads/test.nb.html"

cat(eval(a))
#> C:/Users/joel.kandiah/Downloads/test.nb.html
```

The Rmarkdown document:

```r
if(!exists("data_raw")) simpleError("Dataset has not been loaded")
#> <simpleError: Dataset has not been loaded>
```

What I would like is to see the simple error as an object in the R script. Something akin to an exit code might also be acceptable.

Comment: Im a bit uncertain about the relation between the `R script` and `Rmd`, you have all your codes running in the script, and want to pass possible `errors` to the `Rmd`?

Or do you want the possible `errors` sent back to your `R script` so you can identify where the `error` is?

Comment: Sorry. The latter is the case. That's why I'm forcing an error in the rmarkdown document. I would like to view or track the error in the rscript. The idea being that I can then differentiate between an outcome of an error being generated to control what happens afterwards. (In this case I will later want to email the rmarkdown file to those who need it or I want to send an email with a rough description of the error generated (which I can specify using try catch or something) to a subset of the people)

Comment: OK - I think I understand. See my answer below, which is a starting point of where I believe you are headed. In any case, the answer will put the question in the top! :-)

Comment: What about https://stackoverflow.com/a/62041765/5784831?

Comment: That is a useful thread. Not sure why I hadn't come across this one! I think the answer below works a bit more effectively for what I want though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible approach, is the wrapping `tryCatch`  around `render` in your `R script`.

**R Script**

```
# Render the markdown document; ####
tryCatch(
        expr = rmarkdown::render(
                "markdown.Rmd",
                clean = TRUE
        ),
        
        error = function(cond) {
                
                message(cond)
                
        },
        
        warning = function(cond) {
                
                message(cond)
                
        }
        
)
```

**R Markdown**

```
# Force an error; 
stop("You do not have permission to render. Admin password is needed.")
```

This will return the same `error`-message to your `script`.